# Will RCDs function properly in the Philippines?

Tags: rcd

In the Philippines the two pin plug can go into power socket either way.  Most domestic wirings have an earth at the power pole.

My question is can an RCD be installed and function 100 % in this type of wiring system?

Comment: Search RCD and read my other answers

Answer (score 0):

YES, the RCD uses a common mode transformer to use any differential or unbalanced current to trip a relay.

Only the test resistor uses a small current to create an imbalance to gnd to test it so that test may not function unless rewired. So not quite 100%.

Comment: RCD is residual current detector. If current in is not same as current out, it will trip.

Comment: There are many classes of current trip levels , but I know that

Comment: @Indraneel So how does Test work on 2 pins?

Comment: I don't think test will work. The test button feeds a known current to earth, to check if it will trip at the particular set current. If one really has to ensure that the RCD is working properly, one can use ohms law to calculate a suitable resistor to earth, set it all up and then switch on the RCD, to see if it trips. Actually, you can add that calculation to your answer to make it better, together with tips on how to do it safely.

Comment: Test button works by bypassing the sense transformer from L-N. It does not need earth to operate.

Comment: TY @RoyC .......